# Linear Algebra Dot Product - Subspace/Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXKDe.png)
I'm trying to solve parts b and c for this textbook practice problem and I can't seem to understand how to construct the basis for either of them. Would part b be a subspace because they are multiplying by vector v to get the zero vector?

Comment: Part b is indeed a subspace, because it is the null space of the linear map $v \mapsto v\cdot a$. This should also give you a hint regarding its dimension.

Comment: Therefore the zero vector has dimension zero. Does that mean that the basis would just be an empty set for part B?

Comment: The dimension of the null space of the linear map $v \mapsto v \cdot a$ is $3$, not $0$. This is because the dimension of the image is $1$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ it could only be $0$ or $1$; it's not $0$ because, for example, $a\cdot a \neq 0$). Then rank-nullity tells us that the null space must have dimension $4 - 1 = 3$. So, your basis should have three vectors.

Comment: Please take the time to enter the key parts of your question instead of linking to/uploading an image so that the gist of your question shows up in summaries. You can find a quick reference on how to use MathJax to format your equations and mathematical expressions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you aren’t going to take the time to help others understand what your question is, why do you expect them to take their own time to help you?